# Closing on a single window closes all the frames in java

Tags: java, swing, frame

I would like to make possible the navigation of frames in java.Whenever i close a frame the remaining frames which are also opened get closed;and the entire program stops.

Please help...

Comment: what code are you using when disposing the frame?

Comment: ***Use just one frame!***  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) for more details.

Answer (score 10):

You probably used

```
   //this will terminate or exit your application    
   setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Maybe you want to use this instead,

```
   setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
```

for your reference go to this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to close only that one frame, you should do something like this: `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)`

If you want to close all frames whenever a single frame closes you can do the following:

You could use a window listener and call `System.exit(0);` when the `JFrame` closes, or try `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` on each `JFrame`. That way your program would close all frames and end.

If you need to perform some tasks before application quits, you should probably use the window listener.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do that graphicaly. right click on your frame and select properties and from there you can change that like the below picture.

[image]

Comment: This answer was so helpful i don't know why they have down voted this.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using swing palette. In frame properties choose default close operation as (Dispose). Follow as per the image given in this solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I used a listener found on the basic tutorials :

```
WindowListener l = new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    };

    addWindowListener(l);
```

I know it's dumb. I didn't see it, but some people might have done the same thing, so I'll just leave this here ;)